# How to do recursive file search of hidden files on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I noticed that neither `cmd` nor `powershell` can do recursive file search on files with the hidden attribute.

So is there any way around this? I mean except having to remove the hidden attribute from the file or files in question, for which I would need to know their location beforehand, which would of course make the whole exercise meaningless.

Why is it not working with files that have the hidden attribute? Is this some kind of security feature?

**Example (cmd)**

---

```
C:\>dir /b
Intel
PerfLogs
plant
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
Users
Windows

C:\>cd plant

C:\plant>dir /b
banana.txt

C:\plant>attrib banana.txt
A            C:\plant\banana.txt

C:\plant>attrib -a +h banana.txt

C:\plant>dir /b

C:\plant>dir /b banana.txt
File Not Found

C:\plant>cd /

C:\>dir /b /s banana.txt
File Not Found

C:\>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list hidden files using [PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/25/powertip-display-hidden-files-by-using-powershell/) you'll have to use the `-Force` parameter. So by using `Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse` you'll get a listing of all files, including hidden files.

[`Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Examples`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

> The Force parameter adds hidden files to the display.

Yes, it's not intuitive and the description of the parameter itself doesn't tell you.

For the commandline itself it would be `dir /A` or `dir /AH` to only list hidden files but I'm not sure how you'd search that output.

Comment: Don't you have to type `/a:h` with colon? And if you want to search for hidden and system files, can you use `/a:sh` or `/ash` or do you have to add that separately like `/a:s` and `/a:h`?

Comment: If you run `dir /?` you'll see that the colon is optional (`[/A[[:]attributes]]`). You'd just combine them so it would be `/A:SH` or `/ASH` but this would also mean that the file would have to have both attributes by just using '/A' it seems any of the attributes is included.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Very good answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Command Prompt use /a and /s switches for all files and recursive:

```
/A          Displays files with specified attributes.
/S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
```

Example

```
dir/a/s
```

In Powershell I use same method just with -force instead of /a to show all files:

```
dir -force -s
```

or

```
dir -force -r
```

Also there is ls in Powershell to type 1 less character!

```
ls -force -s
```

or

```
ls -force -r
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the answer was :

- CMD : `dir /a:H /s`
- POWERSHELL : `ls -ah -recurse`   (option -force)